# CRC8 algorithm clarifications

Tags: c, xor, crc, binary-operators

I have stumbled upon this implementation of 8 bit CRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171925/243827

Can someone shed some light on how that table was obtained ? I have uncommented the `crc8_slow` function and tried feeding it with

```
  byte crc;
  byte data[1] = {0x01};
  crc = crc8_slow(0, data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(byte));
  printf("0x%.2X", crc);
```

for `POLY` defined to 4d, d4, a6 or b2. I can't seem to reproduce the value from that table. Also, how do I need to modify that code for a non 0xff initial value of the shift register ?

*EDIT1*:

```
#define POLY              0xB2

byte crc;
byte data[1] = {0x80};
crc = crc8_slow(0, data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(byte));
printf("0x%.2X", crc);

byte crc8_slow(byte crc, byte *data, size_t len)
{
    byte *end;

    if (len == 0)
        return crc;

//    crc ^= 0xff;
    end = data + len;

    do {
        crc ^= *data++;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
    } while (data < end);

//    return crc ^ 0xff;
    return crc;
}
```

Yields `0x01` when ran. I am on an Atmega 8 bits should it matter.

Comment: The "EDIT1" code is not directly runnable, but when made runnable, it gives `0xB2`. I had to add a `typedef unsigned char byte;`.

Comment: @MarkAdler nope, switched everything to `unsigned char` - same result

Comment: You need to post the exact and complete code that you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Poly` is `0x14D` reversed, then shifted right 1 bit to get `0xB2`. The crc is `bit reflected`, which uses right shifts instead of left shifts.

```
101001101      0x14d
101100101      0x14d bit reversed = 0x165
 10110010      0x14d bit reversed >> 1 = 0xB2
```

If you look at `crc8_table[0x80]`, you'll see a `0xB2`. Each row is 12 bytes long, and since index `0x80` is decimal `128`, look at the 10th row starting with `0x1d`, and look at byte 8 (first byte of that row is 120), to see the `0xB2`.

I tested this code and it prints a 0xB2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char byte;
#define POLY              0xB2

// prototype
byte crc8_slow(byte crc, byte *data, size_t len);

int main(){
    byte crc;
    byte data[1] = {0x80};
    crc = crc8_slow(0, data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(byte));
    printf("0x%.2X", crc);
    return 0;
}

byte crc8_slow(byte crc, byte *data, size_t len)
{
    byte *end;
    if (len == 0)
        return crc;
//  crc ^= 0xff;
    end = data + len;
    do {
        crc ^= *data++;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
    } while (data < end);
//  return crc ^ 0xff;
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: err, helpful and confusing :). Can you check my edit ?

Comment: ok, it porbably has to do with my 8 bit architecture. I'll see some more into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The table is the crc8_slow() of the single bytes 0..255 without the initial and final exclusive-ors. That code already has `POLY` defined as `0xb2`, which is the reflection of the given polynomial (`0x4d` bit reversed).

For a different CRC-8 definition with a zero initial register value and no final exclusive-or, just remove the two exclusive-ors from the code.

You can look at [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate CRC code for any given specification.